# Small dry well for secondary bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, sink

I have a very small quarter bathroom that I’d like to convert into a half bath by adding a very small corner sink for hand washing. The problem is that the bathroom floor is concrete that would have to be jackhammered out to run a drainpipe from the sink to join into the sewer line that would be expensive.

The bathroom has an exterior wall. It would therefore be much simpler to punch a hole through the wall and run a pipe to the outside and down into a small dry well. (This is a secondary bathroom that isn’t used very much so the dry well wouldn’t have to be that big.)

I live in Oakland, CA. Is doing something as I’ve suggested above (A) a reasonable solution, (B) would it require a permit, and (C) would it even be legal to do to get a permit?

FYI: the nearby water-heater's overflow pipe currently runs through a hole punched in the wall and drains to outside (with no dry well, but it would only be used in the hopefully unlikely case that causes the water heater to overflow).  This was done by a plumber and passed inspection.

Thanks.

Comment: Concrete slabs are usually cut with a diamond saw, not a jackhammer. The latter can cause a lot of collateral damage. It's not difficult nor expensive. More importantly, are you proposing dumping graywater into the ground? That's rarely legal or wise.

Comment: Water heater over flow would be considered as drinking water.  Drains from sinks is considered grey water and most places will not allow it, guessing CA is even worst.  Cheapest might be to use a 5 or10 gallon pail under sink and empty it into nearby waste water drain, but this might not be permittable either.

Comment: Even _better_, you mean. This planet is messed up enough without unregulated sewage disposal. I would report such activity in a heartbeat.

Comment: In the county areas that are not on city sewer dry wells used to be ok. Now that the entire area tends to be on city sewer it may not be allowed. Note to others grey water is not sewage and just north of this area it is legal I know because I installed it in the past. Cutting the concrete and adding a drain is really not that hard, I would wait until later in the summer even though it’s been a dry winter /spring so far.

Comment: 5-gal bucket under the sink with the smallest sump pump you can find (or rig your own with a float switch and a small transfer pump), then you can run the outlet from the pump however you need to to get to a convenient hookup to the real drain.

Comment: @brhans  That takes out all the exercise potential of carrying a 5 gal bucket around.

Comment: Sink water with a bit of hand soap is the only thing that would go down the drain. It's hardly "sewage."